# Деплой телеграм бота на питоне

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot

У меня есть телеграм бот написанный на питоне. Бот работает с базой данных. Пробовал залить бота на хостинг Pythonanywhere - выбивает ошибку о том, что невозможно подключиться к БД. Я новичек в этом деле, поэтому хотел спросить, может кто подскажет как задеплоить бота, что бы он работал с бд.

Comment: Онлайн или оффлайн бд?

Comment: Если честно, без понятия... Если не сложно, объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы же написали, что бот написан на питоне. Думаете, на каком языке написан бот - это важнее, чем **на какой СУБД база**? Думаете сразу понятно, почему к бд невозможно подключиться просто написав, что "бот выбивает ошибку о том, что невозможно подключиться к БД" и можно не писать, **что именно выбил бот**, ведь это всегда одна и та же общеизвестная среди хакеров, таких как мы, причина?

Comment: @mrEvgenX Я же написал, что новичек в этом, именно для этого я и задал этот вопрос, что бы возможно кто-то объяснил мне. База на mysql, ошибка, которую выбивает бот mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
>>>

Comment: Не причем тут новичок/не новичок. Когда задаешь вопрос совершенно незнакомым людям, как правило боишься что-то упустить и перегружаешь вопрос лишними подробностями. Вы, как вижу, строго держитесь противоположной крайности. Лучше сразу все необходимое включать, перебдеть можно, но не сильно. Вы подключаетесь на локальный хост к порту 3306 и ожидаете, что там будет крутиться база данных. Но ее там нет, порт 3306 закрыт, когда разрабатывали локально, все было в порядке, но после деплоя на сервер... Поднимите базу на том хостинге, например. Либо поменяйте localhost на то, где поднята база.

Comment: Есть такой раздел в справке ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), обязательно изучите его, пожалуйста, там высказано более подробно и наглядно, что я хочу сказать в первой части своего комментария.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Обязательно учту ваши пожелания